# Issue with wp_insert_post when modifying permalinks with “.html” extension

Tags: permalinks

I'm trying to obtain for products and products category the following permalinks structures:
https://mm.mtgeeks.com/product-name.html
https://mm.mtgeeks.com/parent-category-name.html
https://mm.mtgeeks.com/parent-category-name/subcategory-name.html

In order to obtain this I have modified the permalink using the following filters and actions:

```
add_filter( 'request', 'change_requerst_vars_for_product_cat' );
add_filter( 'term_link', 'term_link_filter', 10, 3 );
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'wpp_remove_slug', 10, 3 );
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpp_change_request' );
add_action( 'create_term', 'mee_new_product_cat_edit_success', 10, 2 );//fix 404 errors
add_action('init', 'mee_product_category_rewrite_rules');
add_action('wp_insert_post', 'mt_woo_new_product_post_save');//fix 404 errors
add_action('init', 'mt_woo_product_rewrite_rules');
```

After updating the permalinks from the wordpress admin, on the frontend I obtain the needed permalinks structure, but on the backend I have only one issue.

When trying to do modifications to products I get the following message displayed by google chrome:
"This page isn’t working mm.mtgeeks.com is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500"

After doing some debugging in the wordpress core, I have observed that the product updating process remains blocked in the function wp_insert_post from wp-includes/post.php at line 3962 (do_action( 'wp_insert_post', $post_ID, $post, $update );)

How can I fix this issue? For which purposes is this line of code used?

I've observed that if this line of code is commented out, the updating process is working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I would use the Permalink Manager Lite plugin (free).
or it's PRO version ($39): https://permalinkmanager.pro/
Makes life easier :)